# Отобразить балун (информацию о метке) по клику на неё (Yandex Mapkit)

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Подскажите алгоритм или поделитесь примером как в Yandex Mapkit (Android, Java) отследить клик по метке и вывести информацию о ней (балун). Информация будет предварительно получена для каждой метки, пока основной вопрос именно в том, как выводить балун.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовано следующим образом.

1. Создать метку, сохранить нужную информацию о метке в объект, присвоить метке (`placemark`) данные из объекта (`placemark_data`):

   ```
   placemark.setUserData(placemark_data);
   ```
2. Тут же добавить метке слушатель:

   ```
   placemark.addTapListener(this);
   ```
3. Обработка тапа по метке производится в методе `onMapObjectTap`, например вот так можно вывести данные по метке в TextView:

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectTap(@NonNull MapObject mapObject, @NonNull Point point) {
        PlacemarkInfo.setText(mapObject.getUserData().toString());
        ...
    }
   ```

Необходимо учитывать, что по умолчанию метод `toString()` выведет результат в нечитаемом виде. Чтобы это исправить, нужно переопределить этот метод в классе, экземпляром которого является объект `placemark_data`.